# NSManagedObject; keep or load into a custom NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm using Core Data to store objects. I have a `NSManagedObject` Person and a `NSObject` Person. They both have the same attributes. The `NSObject` has some methods.

Right now, I search Core Data for Bob. I then take that `NSManagedObject` Bob and copy all the attributes to the `NSObject` Bob and do what I need with it.

Does this make sense or should I create the needed methods in the `NSManagedObject` instead? Can a `NSManagedObject` be treated the same as a `NSObject`?

Comment: This is actually a deep question. Most people just use the NSManagedObject directly, but if you want to develop decoupled and flexible code, you would want to keep core data abstracted behind some sort of persistence layer, and use regular NSObject domain objects throughout the rest of your app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An encouraged way is to build a category of your NSManagedObject subclass and implement your custom methods in this category. That way you can re-create your NSManagedObject subclass through Xcode if your schema changes and your category remains intact and unaffected.

Reference: e.g. Paul Hegarty's / Stanfords iOS courses on core data

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use an `NSManagedObject` like a regular object-- it's not just there for data store access, it's intended to be used as your model object directly. Copying data back and forth between instances of different classes like this is a lot of extra work for no benefit.

Since you're adding custom code, I **highly** encourage you to use [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to generate your `NSManagedObject` subclasses. It will make it a lot easier to keep your custom code in place if/when you need to change your model.